# Trying to convert conditional calculations for storage into NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a lot of code for which I perform conditional calculations. The user would make choices on the UI (drop downs, radio buttons, etc.), and based on the choices I would calculate a result for them. Previously, I would use ViewBag to display the calculated results on the view. But now I want to store these using NHibernate and am having difficulty converting it to something that would store the calculated result. I was hoping this would not require a total rewrite.

Here is an example of what I was doing before (example of one condition - NOTE: PriceQuote.cs just holds values) in Calculate.cs:

```
public decimal decSpouseFilingChapter7(QuoteViewModel quoteData)
{
    if (quoteData.QuotePartRecord.MaritalStatusDropDown == 
        MaritalStatus.Yes && 
        quoteData.QuotePartRecord.SpouseFilingRadioButton == 
        SpouseFiling.No)
            return PriceQuote.priceNoSpouseFilingChapter7; // see below
    else if (quoteData.QuotePartRecord.MaritalStatusDropDown == 
        MaritalStatus.Yes && 
        quoteData.QuotePartRecord.SpouseFilingRadioButton == 
        SpouseFiling.Yes)
            return PriceQuote.priceSpouseFilingChapter7; // see below
    else
        return 0;
}
```

PriceQuote.cs would have this (just showing two, it holds over 100+ amounts):

```
public static decimal priceNoSpouseFilingChapter7 { get { return 100; } }
public static decimal priceSpouseFilingChapter7 { get { return 300; } }
```

Further along in Calculate.cs, after a bunch of conditions, I would do this to come up with a calculated result:

```
public decimal TotalChapter7(QuoteViewModel quoteData)
{
    decimal total = PriceQuote.priceChapter7;

    total += this.decSpouseFilingChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decPaymentPlanChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decProcessingChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decSubmissionChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decDistrictChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decUnsecuredCreditor(quoteData);
    total += this.decGarnishment(quoteData);
    total += this.decTaxLiability(quoteData);
    total += this.decRentalEviction(quoteData);
    total += this.decRealEstateChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decRealEstateIntention(quoteData);
    total += this.decVehicleChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decVehicleIntention(quoteData);
    total += this.decOtherAssetChapter7(quoteData);
    total += this.decOtherAssetIntention(quoteData);
    total += this.decFinancialAccount(quoteData);
    total += this.decMeansTestAnalysisChapter7(quoteData);

    return total;
}
```

As you can see, I've added all the other conditionals to show the length of what I have - and this is just one Total, I have dozens more (each with dozens of conditionals).

Can anyone provide some sample code on how I'd convert this, because I am trying to `get/set` by doing something like this:

```
public virtual decimal SpouseFilingChapter7
{
    get
    {
        return decSpouseFilingChapter7;
    }
    set
    {
        decSpouseFilingChapter7 = value;
    }
}
```

so that I might do something like:

```
public virtual decimal TotalChapter7
{
    get
    {
        return SpouseFilingChapter7 + ...;
    }
}
```

but that obviously is wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear what NHibernate has to do with this but here is a possible refactoring

```
class Calculate
{
    private QuoteViewModel _quoteData;
    private PriceQuote _prices;

    public Calculate(QuoteViewModel quoteData, PriceQuote prices)
    {
        _quoteData = quoteData;
        _prices = prices;
    }

    public decimal SpouseFilingChapter7
    {
        get
        {
            if (_quoteData.QuotePartRecord.MaritalStatusDropDown == MaritalStatus.Yes)
            {
                return _quoteData.QuotePartRecord.SpouseFilingRadioButton == SpouseFiling.Yes ?
                    _prices.priceSpouseFilingChapter7 :
                    _prices.priceNoSpouseFilingChapter7;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public decimal TotalChapter7
    {
        get
        {
            return _prices.priceChapter7 +
                SpouseFilingChapter7 +
                PaymentPlanChapter7 +
                ProcessingChapter7 +
                SubmissionChapter7 +
                DistrictChapter7 +
                UnsecuredCreditor +
                Garnishment +
                TaxLiability +
                RentalEviction +
                RealEstateChapter7 +
                RealEstateIntention +
                VehicleChapter7 +
                VehicleIntention +
                OtherAssetChapter7 +
                OtherAssetIntention +
                FinancialAccount +
                MeansTestAnalysisChapter7;
        }
    }
}
```